# Menu selector that changes the background of a selected div

Tags: javascript, jquery, beginner, html, event-handling

I made this code to change the background color for a `div` in a set of `div`s while disabling the rest of the `div`s in the background. It works fine, but I wanted the code reviewed for more improvements since I am new to jQuery and JavaScript.

```
<div id="singleProjectTitle">
    <div  class="ProjectMainLink" id="aboutProject"><div  class="ProjectMainLinkInnerDiv">عن المشروع</div></div>
    <div  class="ProjectMainLink" id="key"><div  class="ProjectMainLinkInnerDiv">المميزات الرئيسية</div></div>
    <div  class="ProjectMainLink" id="map"><div  class="ProjectMainLinkInnerDiv">الخارطة</div></div>
    <div  class="ProjectMainLink" id="galary"><div  class="ProjectMainLinkInnerDiv">البوم الصور والفيديو  </div></div>
</div>


  var count = $(".ProjectMainLink").length;
     for(var i=0; i<count;i++){
         $(".ProjectMainLink").eq(i).click(function() {
              $(".ProjectMainLink").css("background-color","");
            $(this).css("background-color","#fff");

        });
         }
```

Comment: BTW Don't edit your question http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For maintainability, avoid setting the background color directly in JavaScript / jQuery.  Rather, you should keep all styling information in CSS.  Your jQuery code should limit itself to adding or removing classes.  Building on the answer by CodeX…

```
<html dir="rtl">
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      .ProjectMainLink.Selected {
          background-color: #000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="singleProjectTitle">
      <div  class="ProjectMainLink" id="aboutProject"><div  class="ProjectMainLinkInnerDiv">عن المشروع</div></div>
      <div  class="ProjectMainLink" id="key"><div  class="ProjectMainLinkInnerDiv">المميزات الرئيسية</div></div>
      <div  class="ProjectMainLink" id="map"><div  class="ProjectMainLinkInnerDiv">الخارطة</div></div>
      <div  class="ProjectMainLink" id="galary"><div  class="ProjectMainLinkInnerDiv">البوم الصور والفيديو  </div></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on("click", ".ProjectMainLink", function() {
          $(".ProjectMainLink").removeClass("Selected");
          $(this).addClass("Selected");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS should be moved into a separate file rather than inlined in the proof-of-concept above.

The HTML could use some simplification as well.  You'll have to decide whether this simplification is appropriate for you.

```
<html dir="rtl">
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #singleProjectTitle > div.Selected {
          background-color: #000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="singleProjectTitle">
      <div id="aboutProject">عن المشروع</div>
      <div id="key">المميزات الرئيسية</div>
      <div id="map">الخارطة</div>
      <div id="galary">البوم الصور والفيديو</div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on("click", "#singleProjectTitle > div", function() {
          $("#singleProjectTitle > div").removeClass("Selected");
          $(this).addClass("Selected");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`galary` should be spelled `gallery`.

Comment: Completely forgot about those `Class` functions, makes for cleaner code, V.nice

Comment: 200_success♦ thanks for the review and the valuable hints it gave me more control over my script :)i cant remove the inner dives cuz they have their own style before selecting

Answer (score 2):

im not sure why you would want the length or count of the class..
You could simply use this to highlight the divs:

```
    $(".ProjectMainLink").click(function() {
          $(".ProjectMainLink").css("background-color","");
          $(this).css("background-color","#000");

    });
```

JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/p3m2p/

**EDIT:**

Don't forget to wrap your functions in `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

It could also be done like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click",".ProjectMainLink",function() {
          $(".ProjectMainLink").css("background-color","");
          $(this).css("background-color","#000");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks very much iam new to jquery :) thanks for the review it help me understand jquery more .

Comment: Added a full example with `script tags` included